# windows server 2008 terminal server users cannot print

Tags: windows-server-2008, printing

i am running a windows server 2008 system with terminal services. Users login with Remote Desktop Connection. Now the issue is that these users can not print at all within the terminal services. They are trying to print to printers that are added to the server. When i login via administrator everything prints perfectlly fine. This is were i know its a permissions problem but i do not know yet how to solve it.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Dani

Comment: What happens when they try to print, are the printers even visible to them?

Comment: *Sorry guys just created account i am Dani.*

The printers are all visible to them, but when they print they get no error messages at all just nothing comes out.

Maybe i should check the server logs and see if i see anything

Answer (score 1):

Are you using 'Easy Print'? [Apparently](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/962930) you need to give everyone permissions to the printers folder. Amazing.